# Collect text using XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath

is it possible to capture all EAN numbers in such a construct using XPath, or do I need to use regular expressions?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      EAN Giftbox
    </td>
    <td>
      7350034654483
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      EAN Export Carton:
    </td>
    <td>
      17350034643958
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get a list of ['7350034654483', '17350034643958']

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import html as lh

html = """<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      EAN Giftbox
    </td>
    <td>
      7350034654483
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      EAN Export Carton:
    </td>
    <td>
      17350034643958
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""

root = lh.fragment_fromstring(html)

tds = root.xpath('//tr[*]/td[2]')
for td in tds:
    print(td.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
7350034654483
17350034643958
```